# How can I put Elixir's umbrella app names into the logger metadata?

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

[Umbrella apps](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/dependencies-and-umbrella-apps.html) are an interesting feature of Elixir, but I'm surprised the logging by default doesn't show which app is generating a log message.  I'd like to add the umbrella app's name to the Logger metadata, but I'm not sure the best place to do that.  Each app can configure the logger separately it seems and whitelist which metadata to show, but I'm not sure where to add the umbrella metadata

For example in `apps/web/config/dev.exs` I can put

```
config :logger, :console,
  metadata: [:umbrella_app]
```

But then I'm not finding a good place to add something like `Logger.metadata(umbrella_app: :web)` to populate the metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:application` to metadata

```
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:application]
```

This will print message like this

> application=app [level] Message

Comment: This is close to what I want, but this gives me app names like `plug` and `kaffe`, not my umbrella app names.